# SFMCSDK setPushEnabled is ignored

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

I'm trying to implement app settings for the SFMCSDK.
I'm interested in *softly* disabling push notifications.
I'm trying to call `SFMCSdk.mp.setPushEnabled(false)` and receive `SFMCSdk.mp.pushEnabled() == false`.

But disregarding this setting being false or true the phone is still receiving push notifications from the Marketing Cloud.

Please help me understand whether this setting is taking effect at all. Is there some good piece of documentation that can be found on it?

> SFMCSDK 1.0.4
>
> MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.6

Comment: I have updated versions of SDKs to 1.0.5 and 8.0.7 and the problem still persists.

Comment: Open a support case.